# Wrong users number along with dimension by google analytics API

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

When i want to query ga:users with dimension ga:date, I get wrong numbers but if i don't use any dimensions, the result is OK.
For example, the users number in the date 2018-01-01 to 2018-01-31 return 119 users but when i add ga:date dimension, it returns 133.

[image: metrics=ga:users]

[image: metrics=ga:users , dimensions=ga:date]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess users are counted as a sum of lines.

**Example**

Let's say 1 user entered the site every day during 5 days.

If I request report for a period for 5 days I will have 1 user.

If I split report by days I will have 1 user per day. Total (sum of lines) = 5 users

Comment: Yes that's right. i didn't look that way. Actually, I think that is G.A bug cause there is no way to get unique users each day when you use date dimension.